# Navigation drawer - Fragment is not showing

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

EDITED -2

Its like the same one earlier, I tried to do what you did on the first one that I gave and searched some Instructions on converting an Activity to Fragment but all I get is a bunch of errors. Also, do you have a good source tutorial or information on converting this kinds of files? I would really much appreciate it.

```
    public class Lesson111 extends Activity{

    private RadioGroup radioAnswerGroup;
    private RadioButton radioAnswerButton;
    private Button btnSubmit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onepointthree);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        radioAnswerGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAnswer);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                int selectedId = radioAnswerGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find the radiobutton by returned id
                radioAnswerButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

                Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this,
                        radioAnswerButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Here is the main activity

```
public class NavigationActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ImageView home;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    TextView appname;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    List<String> listDataHeader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        home = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home);
        home.setOnClickListener(homeOnclickListener);
        appname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.appname);
        setUpDrawer();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Get the names and icons references to build the drawer menu...
     */
    private void setUpDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        fragment = new Lesson1();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new Lesson1();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new Lesson11();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Activity activity = new Lesson111();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
```

this is not the whole code. But i believe the reason why the fragment is not showing is because of this case statement. Did i missed something?

Comment: This post was already answered here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241327/cannot-resolve-method-maketext)

Answer (score 0):

There is typo error in your code , use `Inflater` instead of `inflater`

```
View rootView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.twopointthree, null);
```

replace with this in your code.

EDIT - 2 , Lesson111 as Fragment

Try this

```
public class Lesson111 extends Fragment{
private RadioGroup radioGroup;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater Inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.twopointthree, null);

    /* Initialize Radio Group and attach click handler */
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.clearCheck();

    /* Attach CheckedChangeListener to radio group */
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if(null!=rb && checkedId > -1){
                Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

public void onClear(View v) {
    /* Clears all selected radio buttons to default */
    radioGroup.clearCheck();
}

public void onSubmit(View v) {
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

In your main activity replace

```
  case 2:
  Activity activity = new Lesson111();
```

with

```
  case 2:
  fragment = new Lesson111();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However Im still having some errors. The setContentView(R.layout.onepointthree); is on red line and says unreachable statement.

Comment: However, Im trying to create it to something like this but im not sure on how to implement it with the code above. 

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer.R;

public class Lesson222 extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twopointthree, null);
        return rootView;

    }
}

Comment: There are no more errors on the java file. Thank you. Meanwhile, when I run the app. The fragment is not showing. I will upload the main activity so that you could see.

Comment: You are confusing yourself between activity and fragment. The above edit presents Lesson111() as fragment.

Comment: Fragment and Activity work in similar way, so that wont be an issue . Try the edited code.. Let me know if any error

Comment: Ok, I tried your code for the Lesson111 java. And I changed already the   case 2:  Activity activity = new Lesson111(); to  case 2: fragment = new Lesson111(); However there is an error on the line  Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); it says that "Cannot resolve 'makeText(com.android.pet.view.Lesson111,java.lang.CharSequence,int)"

Comment: I tried using this code   Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this.getActivity(), rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); i got it from here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787881/the-method-maketext-in-the-type-toast-is-not-applicable-for-the-arguments) and when i tried to run it and click the Lesson111 it forced closed the application

Comment: Thank you for your help. The fragment is showing now. Someone helped me and found out the in xml file twopointthree, there is no radiogroup. It was my bad. So I added the radiogroup and its working now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi good timing! Can you help me out regarding on the activity issue? Im going to edit the code above. Would that be fine with you?