# Cannot Resolve method maketext

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

UPDATE

When I use this code Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); Im recieving the error message saying cannot resolve method maketext. Then I saw this ([The method makeText in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787881/the-method-maketext-in-the-type-toast-is-not-applicable-for-the-arguments)) I applied the code Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this.getActivity(), rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); instead of Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); . the error somehow went away. However, when I try to run the application and click the Lesson111. Its forcing the application to close. Am I missing something?

```
package com.android.pet.view;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer.R;

public class Lesson111 extends Fragment {
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater Inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.twopointthree, null);

    /* Initialize Radio Group and attach click handler */
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.clearCheck();

    /* Attach CheckedChangeListener to radio group */
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
                if(null!=rb && checkedId > -1){
                    Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this.getActivity(), rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onClear(View v) {
    /* Clears all selected radio buttons to default */
        radioGroup.clearCheck();
    }

    public void onSubmit(View v) {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        Toast.makeText(Lesson111.this.getActivity(), rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here what shows on the logcat, Im using Bluestacks as an Emulator

03-27 06:04:19.703 7458-7458/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer, PID: 7458
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.android.pet.view.Lesson111.onCreateView(Lesson111.java:22)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Could you post the logcat plz ? So we can see what exception is thrown when you try to show the Toast. I am thinking Lesson111.this.getActivity() might return null but it is hard to confirm without the logs

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF I already updated the post, Also, Im using bluestacks as an emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error come from line 22

`radioGroup.clearCheck();`

Can you check that the layout twopointthree has a RadioGroup with the id 
radioGroup

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no RadioGroup in twopointthree. I added the radiogroup and its already working and the output is showing already on my navigation drawer. Thank you so much!